# FXRuby move png image on canvas?

Tags: ruby, fxruby

I am writing a program in which the user needs to be able to move an
image around a canvas using his/her mouse. Is this possible to do in
FXRuby, and, if so, how? I'm relatively new to programming, so any help
would be appreciated. Thank you